# Elasticsearch group items by field except null field value

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

for example i have collection:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'photo_1'
    photo_id: 10
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'photo_2'
    photo_id: 10
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'photo_3'
    photo_id: null
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'photo_4'
    photo_id: null
  }
]
```

and i want to group by photo_id except null photo_id to get next collection:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'photo_1'
    photo_id: 10,
    inner_hits: ...
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'photo_3'
    photo_id: null
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'photo_4'
    photo_id: null
  }
]
```

if anyone know how to do this? please)
collapse group bull values also, i need also to use pagination and sorting

updating:

currently im using this query

```
query = {
  from: 0,
  size: 50,
  sort: [{created_at: :desc}],
  query: {},
  collapse: {
    field: 'photo_id',
    inner_hits: {
      name: "items"
    },
  }
}
```

but it collapse items where photo_id is null also. is there an any way to collapse only results with photo_id?

i want to get such results:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'photo_1'
    photo_id: 10,
    inner_hits: ...
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'photo_3'
    photo_id: null
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'photo_4'
    photo_id: null
  }
]
```

Comment: can you please share your expected search result ? And **group by photo_id except null photo_id** this means that you don't want to include those documents that have `photo_id` = null ?

Comment: @ESCoder i have updated post. i want to get distinc results by photo_id, but i want to except from distincting items with photo_id = null, so i want to see => [1,2, 3, null,null,null]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, you need to group the documents based on the `photo_id` value and then also include those documents in the result that have `null` as the `photo_id` field value.

To achieve this, you need to use a combination of [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) with [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html), along with [top hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) to get the aggregated documents in the response.

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "agg1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "photo_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "unique_not_null_photo_id": {
          "top_hits": {
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "photo_id",
                "title"
              ]
            },
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "aggs": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "photo_id"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "null_photo_id": {
          "top_hits": {
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "photo_id",
                "title"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "agg1" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 10,
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "unique_not_null_photo_id" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 2,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.0,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "index1",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "1",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "photo_id" : 10,
                    "title" : "photo_1"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "aggs" : {
      "doc_count" : 2,
      "null_photo_id" : {
        "hits" : {
          "total" : {
            "value" : 2,
            "relation" : "eq"
          },
          "max_score" : 1.0,
          "hits" : [
            {
              "_index" : "index1",
              "_type" : "_doc",
              "_id" : "3",
              "_score" : 1.0,
              "_source" : {
                "photo_id" : null,
                "title" : "photo_3"
              }
            },
            {
              "_index" : "index1",
              "_type" : "_doc",
              "_id" : "4",
              "_score" : 1.0,
              "_source" : {
                "photo_id" : null,
                "title" : "photo_4"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

If you combine the response of `unique_not_null_photo_id` bucket and `null_photo_id` bucket in the application side, you will get your required search result.

Comment: but how pagination will work with this?